# Why does the horizontal scroll doesn't go till the end in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

My code is based on React and I've added a horizontal scroll bar tor a table that contains 13 columns. But the scroll bar scrolls only up to the 10th column. What's the reason for this?

This is my CSS file:

```
.table {
  width: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  // overflow-x: scroll;
}

//for chrome
.table::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0 !important;
}

//for firefox &  internet explorer
.table {
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.table:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px !important;
}

.table:hover {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a js-fiddle or codepen of your code? @Madhumi Munasinghe

Comment: too little information, please include the html and the table's children CSS.